# Mahalanobis distance connection with Euclidean distance

Tags: unit-of-measure, mahalanobis-distance

My question is more about the meaning of Mahalanobis distance when compared to L2 distance.
As a reminder:

- Mahalanobis distance is the distance between a point $x$ and a distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$ can be calculated as: $d_{\text{Mahalanobis }} = \sqrt{(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)}$

Back to the question:
if the Euclidean distance between a point $p_a$ and $p_b$ is for example 0.5 and the Mahalanobis distance between the point $p_a$ and some other distribution $\beta$ is 0.75, could we state that point $p_a$ is closer to $p_b$ than distribution $\beta$?

If not, then under what conditions we could have this comparison valid?

Comment: I made an answer below, but can you clarify what you mean by "distribution $\beta$''? If so, I can perhaps update my answer to take this clarification into account.

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman replied down, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the Mahalanobis metric is perhaps best understood as a weighted Euclidean metric. For example, consider distances in the plane. Then, the Euclidean metric coincides with one's geometric intuition of distance, and the Mahalanobis metric coincides with *costliness of traveling along that distance*, say, treating distance along one axis as "more expensive" than distance along the other axis.

So, if the distance between two points if 0.5 according to the Euclidean metric but the distance between them is 0.75 according to the Mahalanobis metric, then one interpretation is perhaps that *travelling between those two points is more costly than indicated by (Euclidean) distance alone*.

Does this answer?

---

P.S. This interpretation is meaningful in statistics where the general multivariate normal distribution (MVN) can be understood as being derived from the MVN with unit variance by means of a scale transformation: effectively replacing the Euclidean metric in the exponential function with a Mahalanobis metric turns a standard Gaussian distribution into a general one (there is also the mean to consider, but that is secondary).

P.P.S. I'm sure that, in machine learning, there are cases in which using a Mahalanobis metric instead of Euclidean corresponds to more/less heavily penalizing incorrect guesses of one feature than of another. As the other answerer pointed out, Mahalanobis metric absorbs Euclidean as a special case.

Comment: I'm looking for a more rigorous connection, for example can I somehow do a transformation over the Mahalanobis distance that output a quantity which is directly comparable with Euclidean distance? I like the idea of cost, thanks

Comment: So, it sounds to me like you're asking whether or not the map $(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) \mapsto (x-\mu)^T(x-\mu)$ is well-defined and invertible. Is my understanding of the question correct?

Comment: Yes, it's more are they equivalent?

Comment: But what, precisely, does "equivalent" mean? I actually not entirely sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean direct comparison, for example the Eculidean distance is in meters between two points, but Mahalanobis is unit less.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a Euclidean distance directly to a Mahalanobis distance does not make sense, generally.

However, define distribution $\alpha$, such that $\vec{\mu_{\alpha}} = \vec{p_b}$ and $\Sigma_\alpha = I$.  So $\alpha$ is centered at $\vec{p_b}$ and spherical.

The Mahalanobis distance between $\alpha$ and $\vec{p_a}$ is

$$ d_M{(\alpha,p_a)} = \sqrt{(\vec{p_a}-\vec{\mu_\alpha})^T\Sigma_\alpha^{-1}(\vec{p_a}-\vec{\mu_\alpha})} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(p_{a_i}-p_{b_i})^2}$$

Thus the Euclidean distance between $\vec{p_a}$ and $\vec{p_b}$ is the Mahalanobis distance between $\vec{p_a}$ and $\alpha$.

Now you can compare Mahalanobis distances and make a statement that $\vec{p_a}$ is closer to $\alpha$ (which has center $\vec{p_b})$ than to $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks, this seems legit